# Exaction of rows based on value using awk

Tags: awk

I have a tab limited file like this

```
gi NZ 99.54 438 2   0   1   438 18559   18122   0.0  798 

gi NZ 99.77 438 1   0   1   438 1787    2224    0.0  804

gi NZ 99.32 438 3   0   1   438 82769   83206   0.0  253

gi NZ 100.00 438 0  0   1   438 19698   20135   0.0  809
```

from above file i want to extract rows based on the value of 3rd row (<100). how it possible

Desirable output

```
gi NZ 99.54 438 2   0   1   438 18559   18122   0.0  798 

gi NZ 99.77 438 1   0   1   438 1787    2224    0.0  804

gi NZ 99.32 438 3   0   1   438 82769   83206   0.0  253
```

Comment: Do you REALLY have blank lines between each real data line? If not, edit your question to fix your sample input/output. When you say `3rd row (<100)` - do you mean `row` or do you really mean `column`? If you mean `row` then edit your question to clarify in what way the 3rd row is less than 100. If you mean `column` then again edit your question to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just this:

```
awk '$3<100' File
```